# Golang time.Ticker, how to begin on even timestamps

Tags: go

I am attempting to begin a `time.Ticker` on even timestamps. Basically what I want is for this code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second * 5)

    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        select {
        case <-ticker.C:
            fmt.Println("Time: ", time.Now().Round(time.Second*1))
        }
    }

    ticker.Stop()
}
```

To always print on an even 5-second interval:

```
Time:  2015-10-21 12:53:50 -0600 MDT
Time:  2015-10-21 12:53:55 -0600 MDT
```

Is there an elegant solution to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can delay the start of your ticker to get pretty close to an even 5 second time:

```
fiveSec := int64(5 * time.Second)
time.Sleep(time.Duration(fiveSec - (time.Now().UnixNano() % fiveSec)))

ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second * 5)
```

Or another way to get the correct delay with Time methods:

```
time.Sleep(time.Now().Truncate(5 * time.Second).Add(5 * time.Second).Sub(time.Now()))
```

Comment: Just note that if you don't pull from the channel as soon as it is available, the time can skew. No long running-tasks after pulling off.

Comment: @captncraig: true, it's just whether it's acceptable to miss an interval vs skew an interval (which you can control by running tasks asynchronously).

Answer (score 2):

Ticker will always tick relative to the time you start it. Also, if you don't receive fast enough, odd things can happen.

Best I can think of immediately is calculate the duration until the next 5 second interval and use `time.After` to get a signal at that time.

[playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/5f4-8O79NH)

```
const fiveSeconds = int64(5 * time.Second)
for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
    // get current offset from 5 second interval.
    relativeTime := time.Now().UnixNano() % fiveSeconds
    // get remaining time in current 5 second interval.
    waitTime := fiveSeconds - relativeTime
    // wait that long
    ch := time.After(time.Duration(waitTime))
    <-ch
    fmt.Println(time.Now())
}
```

It may be off a bit from exact 5 second intervals, but should be pretty close if you round it.